# How can I solve this PDE kinetics equation with Symbolic Toolbox in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, equation, ode, pde

I want to solve a PDE from a kinetics equation as depicted next:

[Main equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVeVi.png)
which
[kinetic consumption equation of gold](https://i.stack.imgur.com/haurS.png)

I made the following code ,but dont know what i have to change to make it run.

```
syms y(t,z)
U=10;
E_l=1e-8;
cyanide=159;
oxygen=8;
r=0.706e-3*(cyanide^1.38)*(oxygen^0.161)*(y-0.17)^2.19
ode = -(diff(y,t))-U*(diff(y,z,1))+E_l*(diff(y,z,2))-r == 0
ySol = dsolve(ode)
```

So , I want as outcome the solved equation 'Cau' as function of 't' and 'z'
Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: You have a PDE, not an ODE. Matlab's symbolic toolbox can only solve ODEs (for now). If you know that your equation *can* be solved analytically you may access its solving techniques, like separation of variables, and transform it in a set of ODES. Look at their [tsunami example](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve-a-partial-differential-equation-tsunami-simulation.html) for inspiration